# Problems with zooming and mouse events in Openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2

I'm having trouble with everything mouse related for an Openlayers map when the map is placed inside a DIV with position fixed. The map works fine when you're at the top of the viewport of the browser, but when you're scrolling down the page, you can see that the zooming/click effects are shifted.  You can check here http://41.32.148.178:82/#!search=KFC%2F0%2F0%2F0%2F%2F to see exactly what I mean.

Thanks.

Comment: That site (an [unidentified Egyptian server](http://www.ip-adress.com/reverse_ip/41.32.148.178)) is so slow and unresponsive that it doesn't seem to suggest any unusual behavior to me.

Comment: Cannot open URL

Answer (score 1):

I was using an outdated version of openlayers (2.01), updating to the latest version of openlayers solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

you can solve the problem setting the search box a fixed 'height' and using overflow:auto.

The real problem, you suggests, seems related to the compute of map position/dimensions and the fact you move the slider without moving the map.

You can check if calling the 'map.updateSize()' when you move the scroll solves the problem, but IMO i think it is better to set an heigh in the search box to not go beyond the page limits.